# How to add a DataRow into a different DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataRow dr generated from an old DataTable A. Now I want to add it into a new DataTable B. A has same structure with B. I use for() to clone a new DataRow. I wonder a good method to achieve it.

```
            if (hour != this.currentHour)
            {
                ds.Tables.Add(this.currentDataTable);
                this.currentHour = hour;
                this.currentDataTable = InitMeasurementTable();
                this.currentDataTable.TableName = string.Format("Measurement_{0}", hour);
                DataRow drr = this.currentDataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < this.currentDataTable.Columns.Count; ++i)
                    drr[i] = dr[i]; // clone part
                this.currentDataTable.Rows.Add(drr);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DataRow.ItemArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) property.

```
this.currentDataTable.Rows.Add(drr.ItemArray);
```